# create view programmatically

Tags: android, android-view, textview

I am creating views programmatically. every time i run the program, the debug is pointing me at

OperationView operationView = (OperationView) getChildAt(i);

here's my code:

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int size = getWidth();
    int oneTenth = size / 10;

    int count = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (i%2==1){
                Log.d(null,"tile");
                TileView tileView = (TileView) getChildAt(i);
                int tleft = oneTenth * tileView.getCol();
                int ttop = oneTenth * tileView.getRow();
                int tright = oneTenth * tileView.getCol() + oneTenth;
                int tbottom = oneTenth * tileView.getRow() + oneTenth;
                tileView.layout(tleft, ttop, tright, tbottom);
                tileView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }

            else {
                Log.d(null,"operation");
                OperationView operationView = (OperationView) getChildAt(i);
                int oleft = oneTenth * operationView.getCol();
                int otop = oneTenth * operationView.getRow();
                int oright = oneTenth * operationView.getCol() + oneTenth;
                int obottom = oneTenth * operationView.getRow() + oneTenth;
                operationView.layout(oleft, otop, oright, obottom);
                operationView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }           
         }                      
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected class TileView extends TextView{
    private int tileType;
    private int col;
    private int row;

    protected TileView(Context context, int row, int col, int tileType) {
        super(context);
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
        this.tileType = tileType;

        String result = Integer.toString(RandomNumber(1,20));

        Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(tileType);
        setBackgroundDrawable(image);
        setClickable(true);
        setText(result);
        setOnClickListener(GameView.this);          
    }

    public int getTileType(){
        return tileType;
    }


    public int RandomNumber(int min, int max){
        int Result;
        Result = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
        return Result;
    }

    public void setRandomType() {
        tileType = random.nextInt(3);
        //tileType = PickRandomByChance(tileType);
        Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(tileType);
        setBackgroundDrawable(image);
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setCol(int col) {
        this.col = col;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }           
}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected class OperationView extends TextView{
    private int col;
    private int row;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected OperationView(Context context, int row, int col) {
        super(context);
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;

        String result = Character.toString(randomOper());
        //String result = Integer.toString(RandomNumber(1,20));

        Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal);
        setBackgroundDrawable(image);
        setClickable(true);
        setText(result);
        setOnClickListener(GameView.this);          
    }       

    public char randomOper() {    
          oper[0] = '+';
          oper[1] = '-';
          oper[2] = 'x';
          oper[3] = '/';

          if (rounds==3){
              weight1[0] = 60;
              weight1[1] = 20;
              weight1[2] = 20;
              weight1[3] = 0;
          }           
          else{
              weight1[0] = 50;
              weight1[1] = 30;
              weight1[2] = 10;
              weight1[3] = 10;
          }

          weightSum[0] = weight1[0];

          for (z = 1; z < 4; z++) {
              weightSum[z] = weightSum[z-1] + weight1[z];
          }

          for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
              k = rand.nextInt(weightSum[3]);
              for (z = 0; k > weightSum[z]; z++);
              //Log.d(null, "operation: " + oper[z]);                             
          } 
          return oper[z];
      }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public void setCol(int col) {
        this.col = col;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }           
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I go about it?

EDIT: this is the logcat

01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jrs.math.GameView$OperationView
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at com.jrs.math.GameView.onLayout(GameView.java:238)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1243)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1049)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1142)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1861)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
01-12 04:55:05.339: E/AndroidRuntime(29253):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

EDIT: this is how i put the views

```
for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                if ((r % 2) == (c % 2)) {
                    TileView tileView = new TileView(getContext(), c, r,
                            PickRandomByChance());
                    addView(tileView);
                }
                else {
                    OperationView operationView = new OperationView(getContext(), c, r);
                    addView(operationView);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat errors, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: logcat errors posted above

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException   at com.jrs.math.GameView.PickRandomByChance(GameView.java:184)` The error occurs on line 184 in GameView.java, after your reset the game. Post your `PickRandomByChance` method and indicate which line is 184.

Comment: weightSum[y] = weightSum[y-1] + weight[y]; (line 184)

Comment: What is line 184 in GameView.java?

Comment: It appears either `weightSum` or `weight` is smaller than 4...

Comment: How do you build this ViewGroup? The error suggests that not every child is an `OperationView`.

Comment: TileView and OperationView. Is it possible to create 2 views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OperationView operationView = (OperationView) getChildAt(i);
// etc
```

If the ViewGroup's children can either be an OperationView or TitleView, you can use `instanceof` to test which class it is and repeat the same code but cast the child to the appropriate type:

```
View view = getChildAt(i);
if(view instanceof OperationView) {
    OperationView operationView = (OperationView) view;
    // etc using operationView
}
else {
    TitleView titleView = (TitleView) view;
    // etc using titleView
}
```

But a more robust solution is to declare an interface that has the methods `getCol()` and `getRow()` then have OperationView and TitleView implement this interface. Now your code looks like:

```
MyInterface view = (MyInterface) getChildAt(i);
// etc using view
```

(But please use a better name than "MyInterface".)

Answer (score 1):

as your logcat says:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

You are accessing a index that is not in the array.

Are you sure you have initialised your arrays. and to the right size.

```
oper = new char[4];
weight1 = new int[4];
weightSum = new int[4];
```

Make sure your for loops are logical, in that they dont cause a read from the wrong index.

Comment: got rid of that error. but still pointing me on OperationView operationView = (OperationView) getChildAt(i);